# Custom painting in WPF view

Tags: wpf, mvvm, binding

I have a question about doing the custom painting operations in WPF MVVM View. My case is:

External manipulation of model data happens, and the observable collection of data to be shown is modified (storing some data to be shown in a diagram). I have to react to that change in my view, and custom layout the diagram elements (remove the ones not used, place new ones, calculate positions on diagram canvas). How can I do that, and what would be the best way to do it conform to MVVM pattern? I cant subclass the diagram class, as it is sealed. The diagraming framework used is MindFusion.

Edit: A solution was proposed on MindFusion Support forum, and it works.
http://mindfusion.eu/Forum/YaBB.pl?board=wpfdg_disc;action=display;num=1306412889;start=0

Comment: How are you displaying the data now (without responding to changes)?

Comment: Not at all, I am refactoring a Winforms/Nevron application, porting it to WPF with MindFusion diagramming.

Comment: Please add MindFusion to your question to make sure everybody sees that.

Comment: would love to - but get reputation too low cant create a new tag

Comment: A tag might not be needed, add it to the question description

Comment: @PetrOsipov this is a bit odd, you had a Nevron application and you went for MindFusion diagramming tool? Why didn't you just use the [Nevron diagramming tool](https://www.nevron.com/products-dot-net-diagram-overview.aspx), it's quite powerful(at least in my opinion).

Answer (score 0):

Last I checked MindFusion diagraming component for WPF, it supported MVVM through data binding. If you bind the diagram to a ObservableCollection you can then write custom Node Templates which are basically DataTemplate that will render YourDiagramModel items on the diagram panel.

Unlike WinForms you usually don't need to manually refresh or paint control surface in WPF custom controls.

Comment: Hey, I however need to do some custom layouting, as no standard layout can fit there - a very custom diagram type. Or is there a possibility in mindfusion to provide some custom layout engine?